# Error installing PyICU in python 3.6.2 recently installed package

Tags: python, pyicu

So, just installed the newest 3.6.2 python version and updated pip and setuptools, so I started installing PyICU and I got an installation error without, navigating inside internet I have not found the same error, I found some similar in 1.9.5 but did not looked the same. Does anybody has clue?:

> python -m pip install PyICU

```
Collecting PyICU
  Using cached PyICU-1.9.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "MPATH\Temp\pip-build-b_ftb5gu\PyICU\setup.py", line 12, in <module>
        ICU_VERSION = os.environ['ICU_VERSION']
      File " MPATH \Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
        raise KeyError(key) from None
    KeyError: 'ICU_VERSION'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C MPATH \Temp\pip-build-b_ftb5gu\PyICU\setup.py", line 26, in <module>
        ICU_VERSION = check_output(('icu-config', '--version')).strip()
      File " MPATH \Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File " MPATH \Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File " MPATH \Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File " MPATH \Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File " MPATH \Temp\pip-build-b_ftb5gu\PyICU\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
        ''')
    RuntimeError:
    Please set the ICU_VERSION environment variable to the version of
    ICU you have installed.


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in MPATH \Temp\pip-build-b_ftb5gu\PyICU\
```

Comment: have you tried doing what the error message tells you to do?

Comment: @AnthonySottile Um... I did not understand firstly that message. It looks is not installing all dependencies on its own and I need to install ICU, is that correct?

Comment: @TrebiaProject. I think there are certain compatibility issues with `Python 3.6.` try using `3.5` or `2.7`

Comment: Ok, I am reporting it to pyICU development team

Comment: what about something like `export ICU_VERSION=1.7`

Answer (score 4):

If error occured on Linux, `ibicu-dev` should be installed (on Debian):

```
sudo apt-get install libicu-dev
```

Source:https://github.com/ovalhub/pyicu/issues/94

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue on a new Ubuntu install and was able to fix it by installing `pkg-config`, so that the installation could find out which icu-version was installed:

```
sudo apt install pkg-config
```